# Web Service call in JavaScript in ASP.NET : Is there a security issue with my implementation? Is there a better way?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services

I wrote a very simplistic asmx web service.  I setup a script manager in the aspx page and call the web service via JavaScript.  Everything is working fine:

```
   function CallMyWebService(sender,args){
        MyClass.WebService1.HelloWorld(args._value.toString(),1,OnSuccess,OnFail,sender._id.toString();  
   }    
   function OnSuccess(returnStringFromWebService,userContext){
        alert(returnStringFromWebService);
   }
   function OnFail(returnString){
        alert(returnString);
   }
...
   public class WebService1: System.Web.Services.WebService
   {
       [WebMethod()]
       public string HelloWorld(string prefixText, int count)
       {
           return prefixText;
       }
   }
```

The problem is that the class name, asmx file name and method name are all visible via "view source".  I have considered a RESTful web service but it seems if you put a .svc file in your project (instead of the .asmx file) then the calls are similar and you can again see in the project the class name and such.

Is there a security issue here?  Is there some way I can call a web service via JavaScript in ASP.NET that wouldn't expose so much?  If RESTful is the answer?  I would like the web service (asmx or svc) in the same solution as the aspx files.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The browser user will always be able to figure out your URLs.

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry to much about exposing your API.  Sniffers will be able to sniff your calls and call it themselves.  Just make sure that if they call it themselves they can only do what their user/session allows them to do.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about exposing the URLs of your services. That's fine.

If you're concerned about exposing some sensitive data to people who aren't authenticated, you can always change your decorator from:

```
[WebMethod]
```

to:

```
[WebMethod(true)]
```

This will allow you to reference the `Session` variable inside your `WebMethod` calls. Then, you can make sure that the request is coming from someone who's logged in successfully and has the access level required to perform whatever action takes place inside that particular `WebMethod`.

At the very least, you could grab the current user's username and record it somewhere (a database, logfile, event log, etc.) so that you'll know who's trying to access what. This is useful for debugging problems in a `WebMethod`, especially if you have users with different permission levels operating on the same page.